# News Filter EA for MT4

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, mql, mt4

I am builing an EA which fetch news from `http://nfs.faireconomy.media/ff_calendar_thisweek.xml` and set the values to variable `News_Trade_Status`

**Logical Conditions (required):**

Before X minutes from news **==>** `string News_Trade_Status = “Paused”;`

X minutes after news **==>** `string News_Trade_Status = “Paused”;`

**Current Error with Code:**

While setting up an EA, it checks logical conditions and based on that, it sets values to `News_Trade_Status (Active or Paused)`. However, after the setup, it does not repeat the condition check whenever news comes.

**My Code :**

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                      News Filter |
//|                                              Copyright 2018, RRS |
//|                                              example@example.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

#property copyright "NewsFilter"
#property link      "https://example.com"
#import "urlmon.dll"
int URLDownloadToFileW(int pCaller,string szURL,string szFileName,int dwReserved,int Callback);
#import
//---
#define INAME     "FFCPing"+_Symbol
#define TITLE  0
#define COUNTRY 1
#define DATE  2
#define TIME  3
#define IMPACT  4
#define FORECAST 5
#define PREVIOUS 6

input string                p01="***NEWS FILTER***";              //******** NEWS FILTER ******
input bool news_High                  =true;                        //. Use High News Filter
input bool News_High_Line             =true;                        //. Use High news line (Red Line)
input int minBefore                    =120;                         //. Minutes Before High impact News
input int minAfter                     =120;                         //. Minutes After High impact News
input bool news_Medium                =true;                        //. Use Medium News Filter
input bool News_Medium_Line           =true;                        //. Use Medium news line (Orange Line)
input int minBefore1                    =60;                          //. Minutes Before Medium impact News
input int minAfter1                     =60;                          //. Minutes After Medium impact News
input bool news_Low                   =true;                        //. Use Low News Filter
input bool News_Low_Line              =true;                        //. Use Low news line (Yellow Line)
input int minBefore2                    =30;                          //. Minutes Before Low impact News
input int minAfter2                     =30;                          //. Minutes After Low impact News

//News status
int comment_on = 1;
string News_Trade_Status = "Paused";

string xmlFileName;
string sData;
string Event[200][7];
string eTitle[200][200],eCountry[200][200],eImpact[200][200],eForecast[200][200],ePrevious[200][200];
bool assignVal=true;
int eMinutes[10];
datetime eTime[200][200];

datetime xmlModifed;
int TimeOfDay;
datetime Midnight;
bool IsEvent;

//Oninst

int OnInit()
  {

//--- get today time
   TimeOfDay=(int)TimeLocal()%86400;
   Midnight=TimeLocal()-TimeOfDay;
//--- set xml file name ffcal_week_this (fixed name)
   xmlFileName=INAME+"-ffcal_week_this.xml";
//--- checks the existence of the file.
   if(!FileIsExist(xmlFileName))
     {
      xmlDownload();
      xmlRead();
     }
//--- else just read it
   else
      xmlRead();
//--- get last modification time
   xmlModifed=(datetime)FileGetInteger(xmlFileName,FILE_MODIFY_DATE,false);
//--- check for updates
   if(!FileIsExist(xmlFileName))
     {
      if(xmlModifed<TimeLocal()-(4*3600))
        {
         Print(INAME+": xml file is out of date");
         xmlUpdate();
        }
      //--- set timer to update old xml file every x hours

      EventSetTimer(4*3600);
     }
   assignVal=true;
   
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
  
 int deinit()
  {
  
    return (0);
  }

//Onstart
  
  int start()
  {
  
 string display_text = "News Status:" + News_Trade_Status;
 Comment(display_text);
  
  if(!isNewsPause(_Symbol,0)) { News_Trade_Status = "Active"; }
  
  
     return (0);
  }
  
 //Functions

           
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTimer()
  {
//---
   assignVal=true;
   Print(INAME+": xml file is out of date");
   xmlUpdate();
//---
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Creating Text object                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool TextCreate(const long              chart_ID=0,               // chart's ID
                const string            name="Text",              // object name
                const int               sub_window=0,             // subwindow index
                datetime                time=0,                   // anchor point time
                double                  price=0,                  // anchor point price
                const string            text="Text",              // the text itself
                const color             clr=clrRed,               // color
                const string            font="Arial",             // font
                const int               font_size=10,             // font size
                const double            angle=0.0,                // text slope
                const ENUM_ANCHOR_POINT anchor=ANCHOR_LEFT_LOWER, // anchor type
                const bool              back=false,               // in the background
                const bool              selection=false,          // highlight to move
                const bool              hidden=true,              // hidden in the object list
                const long              z_order=0)                // priority for mouse click
  {

//--- reset the error value
   ResetLastError();
//--- create Text object
   if(!ObjectCreate(chart_ID,name,OBJ_TEXT,sub_window,time,price))
     {
      Print(__FUNCTION__,
            ": failed to create \"Text\" object! Error code = ",GetLastError());
      return(false);
     }
//--- set the text
   ObjectSetString(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_TEXT,text);
//--- set text font
   ObjectSetString(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_FONT,font);
//--- set font size
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_FONTSIZE,font_size);
//--- set the slope angle of the text
   ObjectSetDouble(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_ANGLE,angle);
//--- set anchor type
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_ANCHOR,anchor);
//--- set color
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clr);
//--- display in the foreground (false) or background (true)
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_BACK,back);
//--- enable (true) or disable (false) the mode of moving the object by mouse
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_SELECTABLE,selection);
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_SELECTED,selection);
//--- hide (true) or display (false) graphical object name in the object list
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_HIDDEN,hidden);
//--- set the priority for receiving the event of a mouse click in the chart
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_ZORDER,z_order);
//--- successful execution
   return(true);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Create the horizontal line                                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool VLineCreate(const long            chart_ID=0,        // chart's ID
                 const string          name="VLine",      // line name
                 const int             sub_window=0,      // subwindow index
                 datetime              time=0,            // line time
                 const color           clr=clrRed,        // line color
                 const ENUM_LINE_STYLE style=STYLE_SOLID, // line style
                 const int             width=1,           // line width
                 const bool            back=false,        // in the background
                 const bool            selection=false,   // highlight to move
                 const bool            hidden=true,       // hidden in the object list
                 const long            z_order=0)         // priority for mouse click
  {
//--- create a vertical line
   if(!ObjectCreate(chart_ID,name,OBJ_VLINE,sub_window,time,0))
     {

      return(false);
     }
//--- set line color
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clr);
//--- set line display style
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_STYLE,style);
//--- set line width
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_WIDTH,width);
//--- display in the foreground (false) or background (true)
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_BACK,back);
//--- enable (true) or disable (false) the mode of moving the line by mouse
//--- when creating a graphical object using ObjectCreate function, the object cannot be
//--- highlighted and moved by default. Inside this method, selection parameter
//--- is true by default making it possible to highlight and move the object
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_SELECTABLE,selection);
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_SELECTED,selection);
//--- hide (true) or display (false) graphical object name in the object list
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_HIDDEN,hidden);
//--- set the priority for receiving the event of a mouse click in the chart
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_ZORDER,z_order);
//--- successful execution
   return(true);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool HLineCreate(const long            chart_ID=0,        // chart's ID
                 const string          name="HLine",      // line name
                 const int             sub_window=0,      // subwindow index
                 double                price=0,           // line price
                 const color           clr=clrRed,        // line color
                 const ENUM_LINE_STYLE style=STYLE_SOLID, // line style
                 const int             width=1,           // line width
                 const bool            back=false,        // in the background
                 const bool            selection=false,    // highlight to move
                 const bool            hidden=true,       // hidden in the object list
                 const long            z_order=0)         // priority for mouse click
  {
//--- reset the error value
   ResetLastError();
//--- create a horizontal line
   if(!ObjectCreate(chart_ID,name,OBJ_HLINE,sub_window,0,price))
     {
      Print(__FUNCTION__,
            ": failed to create a horizontal line! Error code = ",GetLastError());
      return(false);
     }
//--- set line color
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_COLOR,clr);
//--- set line display style
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_STYLE,style);
//--- set line width
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_WIDTH,width);
//--- display in the foreground (false) or background (true)
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_BACK,back);
//--- enable (true) or disable (false) the mode of moving the line by mouse
//--- when creating a graphical object using ObjectCreate function, the object cannot be
//--- highlighted and moved by default. Inside this method, selection parameter
//--- is true by default making it possible to highlight and move the object
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_SELECTABLE,selection);
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_SELECTED,selection);
//--- hide (true) or display (false) graphical object name in the object list
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_HIDDEN,hidden);
//--- set the priority for receiving the event of a mouse click in the chart
   ObjectSetInteger(chart_ID,name,OBJPROP_ZORDER,z_order);
//--- successful execution
   return(true);
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void xmlDownload()
  {
   Sleep(3000);
//---
   ResetLastError();
   /*string sUrl="http://nfs.faireconomy.media/ff_calendar_thisweek.xml";
   string FilePath=StringConcatenate(TerminalInfoString(TERMINAL_DATA_PATH),"\\MQL4\\files\\",xmlFileName);
   int FileGet=URLDownloadToFileW(NULL,sUrl,FilePath,0,NULL);
   if(FileGet==0)
      PrintFormat(INAME+": %s file downloaded successfully!",xmlFileName);
   //--- check for errors
   else
      PrintFormat(INAME+": failed to download %s file, Error code = %d",xmlFileName,GetLastError());*/

   string cookie=NULL, headers;
   string reqheaders="User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0\r\n";
   char post[],result[];
   int res;
   string url="http://nfs.faireconomy.media/ff_calendar_thisweek.xml";
   ResetLastError();
   int timeout=5000;
   res=WebRequest("GET",url,reqheaders,timeout,post,result,headers);
   if(res==-1)
     {
      Print("Error in WebRequest. Error code  =",GetLastError());
      //--- Perhaps the URL is not listed, display a message about the necessity to add the address
      MessageBox("Add the address '"+url+"' in the list of allowed URLs on tab 'Expert Advisors'","Error",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
     }
   else
     {
      //--- Load successfully
      PrintFormat("The file has been successfully loaded, File size =%d bytes.",ArraySize(result));
      //--- Save the data to a file
      int filehandle=FileOpen(xmlFileName,FILE_WRITE|FILE_BIN);
      //--- Checking errors
      if(filehandle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
        {
         //--- Save the contents of the result[] array to a file
         FileWriteArray(filehandle,result,0,ArraySize(result));
         //--- Close the file
         FileClose(filehandle);
        }
      else
         Print("Error in FileOpen. Error code=",GetLastError());
     }
//---
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Read the XML file                                                |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void xmlRead()
  {
//---
   ResetLastError();
   sData="";
   ulong pos[];
   int   size_;
   Print("Reading file");
   int FileHandle=FileOpen(xmlFileName,FILE_READ|FILE_BIN|FILE_ANSI);
   if(FileHandle!=INVALID_HANDLE)
     {
      //--- receive the file size
      ulong size=FileSize(FileHandle);
      //--- read data from the file
      while(!FileIsEnding(FileHandle))
         sData=FileReadString(FileHandle,(int)size);
      //--- close
      FileClose(FileHandle);
     }
//--- check for errors
   else
      PrintFormat(INAME+": failed to open %s file, Error code = %d",xmlFileName,GetLastError());
   Print("Done.");
//---
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Check for update XML                                             |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void xmlUpdate()
  {
   Sleep(3000);
//--- do not download on saturday
   if(TimeDayOfWeek(Midnight)==6)
      return;
   else
     {
      Print(INAME+": check for updates...");
      Print(INAME+": delete old file");
      FileDelete(xmlFileName);
      xmlDownload();
      xmlRead();
      xmlModifed=(datetime)FileGetInteger(xmlFileName,FILE_MODIFY_DATE,false);
      PrintFormat(INAME+": updated successfully! last modified: %s",(string)xmlModifed);
     }
//---
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Converts ff time & date into yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm - by deVries       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
string MakeDateTime(string strDate,string strTime)
  {
//---
   int n1stDash=StringFind(strDate, "-");
   int n2ndDash=StringFind(strDate, "-", n1stDash+1);

   string strMonth=StringSubstr(strDate,0,2);
   string strDay=StringSubstr(strDate,3,2);
   string strYear=StringSubstr(strDate,6,4);

   string tempStr[];
   StringSplit(strTime,StringGetCharacter(":",0),tempStr);
   int nTimeColonPos=StringFind(strTime,":");
   string strHour=tempStr[0];
   string strMinute=StringSubstr(tempStr[1],0,2);
   string strAM_PM=StringSubstr(tempStr[1],2,2);

   int nHour24=StringToInteger(strHour);
   if((strAM_PM=="pm" || strAM_PM=="PM") && nHour24!=12)
      nHour24+=12;
   if((strAM_PM=="am" || strAM_PM=="AM") && nHour24==12)
      nHour24=0;
   string strHourPad="";
   if(nHour24<10)
      strHourPad="0";
   return((strYear+"."+strMonth+"."+strDay+" "+strHourPad+nHour24+":"+strMinute));
//---
  }

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Convert day of the week to text                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
string DayToStr(datetime time)
  {
   int ThisDay=TimeDayOfWeek(time);
   string day="";
   switch(ThisDay)
     {
      case 0:
         day="Sun";
         break;
      case 1:
         day="Mon";
         break;
      case 2:
         day="Tue";
         break;
      case 3:
         day="Wed";
         break;
      case 4:
         day="Thu";
         break;
      case 5:
         day="Fri";
         break;
      case 6:
         day="Sat";
         break;
     }
   return(day);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Convert months to text                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
string MonthToStr()
  {
   int ThisMonth=Month();
   string month="";
   switch(ThisMonth)
     {
      case 1:
         month="Jan";
         break;
      case 2:
         month="Feb";
         break;
      case 3:
         month="Mar";
         break;
      case 4:
         month="Apr";
         break;
      case 5:
         month="May";
         break;
      case 6:
         month="Jun";
         break;
      case 7:
         month="Jul";
         break;
      case 8:
         month="Aug";
         break;
      case 9:
         month="Sep";
         break;
      case 10:
         month="Oct";
         break;
      case 11:
         month="Nov";
         break;
      case 12:
         month="Dec";
         break;
     }
   return(month);
  }

string nextNews="...";
int total=0;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int UpcomingNewsImpact(string symb,int n)
  {
   nextNews="...";
   string MainSymbol=StringSubstr(symb,0,3);
   string SecondSymbol=StringSubstr(symb,3,3);
//---
   if(assignVal)
     {
      //--- BY AUTHORS WITH SOME MODIFICATIONS
      //--- define the XML Tags, Vars
      string sTags[7]= {"<title>","<country>","<date><![CDATA[","<time><![CDATA[","<impact><![CDATA[","<forecast><![CDATA[","<previous><![CDATA["};
      string eTags[7]= {"</title>","</country>","]]></date>","]]></time>","]]></impact>","]]></forecast>","]]></previous>"};
      int index=0;
      int next=-1;
      int BoEvent=0,begin=0,end=0;
      string myEvent="";
      //--- Minutes calculation
      datetime EventTime=0;
      int EventMinute=0;
      //--- split the currencies into the two parts

      //--- loop to get the data from xml tags
      while(true)
        {
         BoEvent=StringFind(sData,"<event>",BoEvent);
         if(BoEvent==-1)
            break;
         BoEvent+=7;
         next=StringFind(sData,"</event>",BoEvent);
         if(next == -1)
            break;
         myEvent = StringSubstr(sData,BoEvent,next-BoEvent);
         BoEvent = next;
         begin=0;
         for(int i=0; i<7; i++)
           {
            Event[index][i]="";
            next=StringFind(myEvent,sTags[i],begin);
            //--- Within this event, if tag not found, then it must be missing; skip it
            if(next==-1)
               continue;
            else
              {
               //--- We must have found the sTag okay...
               //--- Advance past the start tag
               begin=next+StringLen(sTags[i]);
               end=StringFind(myEvent,eTags[i],begin);
               //---Find start of end tag and Get data between start and end tag
               if(end>begin && end!=-1)
                  Event[index][i]=StringSubstr(myEvent,begin,end-begin);
              }
           }
         //--- filters that define whether we want to skip this particular currencies or events

         //if(!IsCurrency(Event[index][COUNTRY]))
         //continue;
         /*if(importance!=0 && Event[index][IMPACT]=="High")
            continue;
         if(importance!=1 && Event[index][IMPACT]=="Medium")
            continue;
         if(importance!=2 && Event[index][IMPACT]=="Low")
            continue;
         if(!IncludeSpeaks && StringFind(Event[index][TITLE],"Speaks")!=-1)
            continue;
         if(!IncludeHolidays && Event[index][IMPACT]=="Holiday")
            continue;*/
         if(Event[index][TIME]=="Tentative" ||
            Event[index][TIME]=="")
            continue;

         //--- sometimes they forget to remove the tags :)
         if(StringFind(Event[index][TITLE],"<![CDATA[")!=-1)
            StringReplace(Event[index][TITLE],"<![CDATA[","");
         if(StringFind(Event[index][TITLE],"]]>")!=-1)
            StringReplace(Event[index][TITLE],"]]>","");
         if(StringFind(Event[index][TITLE],"]]>")!=-1)
            StringReplace(Event[index][TITLE],"]]>","");
         //---
         if(StringFind(Event[index][FORECAST],"&lt;")!=-1)
            StringReplace(Event[index][FORECAST],"&lt;","");
         if(StringFind(Event[index][PREVIOUS],"&lt;")!=-1)
            StringReplace(Event[index][PREVIOUS],"&lt;","");

         //--- set some values (dashes) if empty
         if(Event[index][FORECAST]=="")
            Event[index][FORECAST]="---";
         if(Event[index][PREVIOUS]=="")
            Event[index][PREVIOUS]="---";
         //--- Convert Event time to MT4 time
         string evD=MakeDateTime(Event[index][DATE],Event[index][TIME]);
         EventTime=datetime(evD);
         index++;
        }
      //--- loop to set arrays/buffers that uses to draw objects and alert
      for(int ii=0; ii<index; ii++)
        {
         if(Event[index][TIME]=="All Day" && Event[ii][IMPACT]=="Holiday" && (MainSymbol==Event[ii][COUNTRY] || SecondSymbol==Event[ii][COUNTRY]))
            return 1;
         eTitle[i][n]    = Event[ii][TITLE];
         eCountry[ii][n]  = Event[ii][COUNTRY];
         eImpact[ii][n]   = Event[ii][IMPACT];
         eTime[ii][n]     = datetime(MakeDateTime(Event[ii][DATE],Event[ii][TIME]))-TimeGMTOffset();
         //Print(eTitle[i]);
        }
      total=index;
     }


   datetime tn=TimeCurrent();
   for(int qi=0; qi<total; qi++)
     {
      if(MainSymbol!=eCountry[qi][n] && SecondSymbol!=eCountry[qi][n])
         continue;
      if(news_High && (eImpact[qi][n]=="High"))
        {
         if(News_High_Line)
            VLineCreate(0,"Tr_VLine"+TimeToString(eTime[qi][n]),0,eTime[qi][n],clrRed,STYLE_SOLID);
        }
      if(news_Medium && (eImpact[qi][n]=="Medium"))
        {
         if(News_Medium_Line)
            VLineCreate(0,"Tr_VLine"+TimeToString(eTime[qi][n]),0,eTime[qi][n],clrOrange,STYLE_SOLID);
        }
      if(news_Low && (eImpact[qi][n]=="Low"))
        {
         if(News_Low_Line)
            VLineCreate(0,"Tr_VLine"+TimeToString(eTime[qi][n]),0,eTime[qi][n],clrYellow,STYLE_SOLID);
        }

      if(news_High && (eImpact[qi][n]=="High") && eTime[qi][n]<(tn+minAfter*60) && eTime[qi][n]>(tn-minBefore*60))
        {
         return 1;
         if(News_High_Line)
            VLineCreate(0,"Tr_VLine"+TimeToString(eTime[qi][n]),0,eTime[qi][n],clrRed,STYLE_SOLID);
        }
      if(news_Medium && (eImpact[qi][n]=="Medium") && eTime[qi][n]<(tn+minAfter1*60) && eTime[qi][n]>(tn-minBefore1*60))
        {
         return 1;
         if(News_Medium_Line)
            VLineCreate(0,"Tr_VLine"+TimeToString(eTime[qi][n]),0,eTime[qi][n],clrOrange,STYLE_SOLID);
        }
      if(news_Low && (eImpact[i][n]=="Low") && eTime[i][n]<(tn+minAfter2*60) && eTime[qi][n]>(tn-minBefore2*60))
        {
         return 1;
         if(News_Low_Line)
            VLineCreate(0,"Tr_VLine"+TimeToString(eTime[qi][n]),0,eTime[qi][n],clrYellow,STYLE_SOLID);
        }
     }
   return(-1);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool isNewsPause(string Symb,int n)
  {
   bool res=false;
   res=(UpcomingNewsImpact(Symb,n)==1);
   return res;
  }
```